# print files from a folder

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I have a folder called "test". I need a c++ code that helps me to print all the files from that folder. I don't want to use inotify or ls.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get a list of files in a directory using C or C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c)

Comment: why is this not a real question?

Comment: it's a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a kernel API called inotify that permits to track changes in a directory. A tutorial for inotify is available from IBM [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/index.html) (this could be an alternative to polling the directory for changes, as I understood you want to do...).

Answer (score 0):

```
<dir.h>
```

Next time please do a minimum research by yourself before asking.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I'd recommend is to use `boost::filesystem` for reading the
directory (and manipulating paths), and `boost::reg_ex` (or
`std::reg_ex` if you have C++11) for checking which filenames match a
pattern.